# How to test if Outlook is open?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

How do I test for Outlook, to bypass opening.

```
if outlook.application "is available" then
      'run the command for sending an email
else
      'open/display the current users document folder
end if

'do some stuff...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code first checks whether Outlook is already running.  If so, the application is assigned to olApp.  If not, it starts the application, if available, and assigns it to olApp.

```
Dim olApp As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If olApp Is Nothing Then
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0

If Not olApp Is Nothing Then
    'run the command for sending an email
Else
    'open/display the current users document folder
End If

'do some stuff...

Set olApp = Nothing
```